# Ricatti differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I attempting to solve some Riccati differential equations.  It has been a while since I have worked with differential equations so I am rusty.  I would appreciate if someone would show me how to do the following example from my book which they did not do the work for.  Then maybe I should be able to do some on my own.

$dS/dt=-G(t)^2S(t)^2$

The solution is $(1/S(0)+\int_0^t G(r)^2 dr)^{-1}$. I can prove this solution is correct but I cannot find the solution on my own.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it definitely $G(t)^2$?  I'm not sure of the context here but that solution looks a lot like separation of variables if it were just $G$.

Comment: or he is just missing the exponent in the solution.

Comment: Also a possibility :)

Comment: It is missing the squared in the solution which I have fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{S(t)} =  -\dfrac{dS/dt}{S(t)^2}$. What does the Riccati equation imply about the RHS?

Comment: I can't resist pointing out the following irony in me being the first to give an answer: The WKB method in quantum mechanics is premised on the ability to convert the Schrodinger equation to a Riccati equation. And the WKB method is a _semiclassical_ method...

Comment: Yeah this was ridiculously easy.  As I said it had been a while since I have done DEs so I had a brain freeze.